# Scrape number of articles on a topic per year from NYT and WSJ?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I would like to create a data frame that scrapes the NYT and WSJ and has the number of articles on a given topic per year. That is:

```
      NYT   WSJ
2011   2     3
2012   10    7
```

I found [this](http://www.stanford.edu/~cengel/cgi-bin/anthrospace/scraping-new-york-times-articles-with-r) tutorial for the NYT but is not working for me :_(. When I get to line 30 I get this error:

```
> cts <- as.data.frame(table(dat))
Error in provideDimnames(x) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

PS: This is my code that is not working (A NYT api key is needed http://developer.nytimes.com/apps/register)

```
# Need to install from source http://www.omegahat.org/RJSONIO/RJSONIO_0.2-3.tar.gz
# then load:
library(RJSONIO)

### set parameters ###
api <- "API key goes here" ###### <<<API key goes here!!

q <- "MOOCs" # Query string, use + instead of space
records <- 500 # total number of records to return, note limitations above

# calculate parameter for offset
os <- 0:(records/10-1)

# read first set of data in
uri <- paste ("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?format=json&query=", q, "&offset=", os[1], "&fields=date&api-key=", api, sep="")
raw.data <- readLines(uri, warn="F") # get them
res <- fromJSON(raw.data) # tokenize
dat <- unlist(res$results) # convert the dates to a vector

# read in the rest via loop
for (i in 2:length(os)) {
  # concatenate URL for each offset
  uri <- paste ("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?format=json&query=", q, "&offset=", os[i], "&fields=date&api-key=", api, sep="")
  raw.data <- readLines(uri, warn="F")
  res <- fromJSON(raw.data)
  dat <- append(dat, unlist(res$results)) # append
}

# aggregate counts for dates and coerce into a data frame
cts <- as.data.frame(table(dat))

# establish date range
dat.conv <- strptime(dat, format="%Y%m%d") # need to convert dat into POSIX format for this
daterange <- c(min(dat.conv), max(dat.conv))
dat.all <- seq(daterange[1], daterange[2], by="day") # all possible days

# compare dates from counts dataframe with the whole data range
# assign 0 where there is no count, otherwise take count
# (take out PSD at the end to make it comparable)
dat.all <- strptime(dat.all, format="%Y-%m-%d")
# cant' seem to be able to compare Posix objects with %in%, so coerce them to character for this:
freqs <- ifelse(as.character(dat.all) %in% as.character(strptime(cts$dat, format="%Y%m%d")), cts$Freq, 0)

plot (freqs, type="l", xaxt="n", main=paste("Search term(s):",q), ylab="# of articles", xlab="date")
axis(1, 1:length(freqs), dat.all)
lines(lowess(freqs, f=.2), col = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

> UPDATE: the repo is now at https://github.com/rOpenGov/rtimes

There is a `RNYTimes` package created by Duncan Temple-Lang https://github.com/omegahat/RNYTimes - but it is outdated because the NYTimes API is on v2 now. I've been working on one for political endpoints only, but not relevant for you.

I'm rewiring `RNYTimes` right now...Install from github. You need to install `devtools` first to get `install_github`

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("rOpenGov/RNYTimes")
```

Then try your search with that, e.g,

```
library(RNYTimes); library(plyr)
moocs <- searchArticles("MOOCs", key = "<yourkey>")
```

This gives you number of articles found

```
moocs$response$meta$hits

[1] 121
```

You could get word counts for each article by

```
as.numeric(sapply(moocs$response$docs, "[[", 'word_count'))

[1]  157  362 1316  312 2936 2973  355 1364   16  880
```

Comment: Thanks! I cannot install "install_github" :_( It is not available for R 3.0.2 :_( Any way around that?

Comment: sorry, you need the `devtools` package for that, Ill edit my answer above. If you are on windows you may run into problems installing devtools, but should be smooth if you're unix

Comment: Thanks! I was able to install it and run it. I almost have what I need now. When I run MOOCs<-searchArticles("MOOCs", key = "<yourkey>") I get a data list of 3. Can you help me transform that into the simple data frame that I need?

Comment: Added some examples above. I think what you want is just `moocs$response$meta$hits` to get number of articles found.

Comment: Almost perfect. What I want is moocs$response$meta$hits for each year. Is that possible? Also, if I do a search using their web interface I find 391 results. Why the difference?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why the difference, There's a lot of options for the article search api I haven't explored yet http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2 - Will work on that soon for RNYTimes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49602/discussion-between-ignacio-and-scott-chamberlain)

Comment: I posted a response in the chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49602/discussion-between-ignacio-and-scott-chamberlain